# rollover parent and be replaced by child elements

Tags: css

I am trying to design a navbar similar tothis one: `http://seelview.ro` **NSFW!** Especially the behavior of Music Events item! If anyone can explain to me how it is done I will be gratefull.

Comment: please clarify exactly what aspect of the menu you want to replecate.

Comment: The rollover of the Music Events on hover and the rollover appearence of its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked to uses jquery animate on the `top` and `opacity` properties to achieve that "roll over" effect. here is the relevant code
html:

```
<li id="ev"><span style="opacity: 1; top: 0px;">Music Events</span>
              <ul class="secondary" style="display: none; opacity: 0; top: 25px;">
                <li><a href="/on-the-set">On the set</a></li>
                <li><a href="/concerts">Concerts</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
```

javascript:

```
var menu_active = false;
navSecTimeout = setTimeout('',1);

function menu_anim($elem) {
    $elem.find("span").stop().animate({opacity: "1",top: "0px"}, 300);
    $elem.find("ul.secondary").stop().animate({opacity: "0",top: "25px"}, 300,function() {
        $(this).hide(); 
    });
}

$("#ev, #pe").mouseenter(
    function() {
        if (menu_active == true) {
            menu_anim($active_elem); 
        }
        menu_active = true;
        $(this).find("span").stop().animate({opacity: "0",top: "-15px"}, 200); //-25px
        $(this).find("ul.secondary").stop().show().animate({opacity: "1",top: "0px"}, 200); //-10px
        $active_elem = $(this);
        clearTimeout(navSecTimeout);
}).mouseleave(
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        navSecTimeout = setTimeout(
            function(){
                menu_active = false;    
                menu_anim($this);
            }
        , 1000);
});
```